# how to set ng-map marker visibility?

Tags: angular, ng-map

I am trying to set ng-map marker visibility option via html attribute.
I've been struggling with about two hours.
Thank you in advance.

```
<div ng-app="mapApp" ng-controller="mapController">
    <ng-map default-style="true" zoom="5" center="usa">

        <marker
                position="usa" options="{visible:false}">
        </marker>
    </ng-map>
</div>
```

Here is my fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/AlexLavriv/La52ggbw/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ng-if` to disable the marker

```
<div ng-app="mapApp" ng-controller="mapController">
    <ng-map default-style="true" zoom="5" center="usa">

        <marker ng-if="showMarkers"
                position="usa" options="{...}">
        </marker>
    </ng-map>
</div>
```

In your controller

```
$scope.showMarkers=false;
```

**[LIVE DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/j785e7nc/)**